# Vertically center text inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a paragraph inside div(class row in bootstrap) and i want to vertically center the text inside the paragraph but i cannot seem to do it.Here is my code and jsfiddle...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="footer" class="row">
    <p id="text" >TEXT</p>
    <img id="facebook" class="img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/59x57" style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-right:15px;margin-top:15px;">
    <img id="adresa" class="img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/59x57"  style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-right:15px;margin-top:15px;">
    <img id="poruka" class="img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/59x57"  style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-right:15px;margin-top:15px;">
    <img id="telefon" class="img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/59x57"  style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-right:15px;margin-top:15px;">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T8Pjh/3/

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the CSS you've tried?

Comment: According to the bootstrap docs, "only columns may be immediate children of rows."

Answer (score 1):

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/T8Pjh/10/)

```
#footer {
    background:pink; /* for visual reference */
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}

#footer p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: i tried this,and it does vertically center my text but now it leaves a bit of white space at the right side...half of it is from padding and half from margin.I set the padding to 0 and it resizes a bit but margin doesnt change even if i set it to 0 it always leaves a bit of white space.

Comment: also now i cant horizontally center my text.